# Open source terminal server to replace MS Terminal Server

Tags: server, software-recommendation

Does anybody know an alternative MS Terminal Server for Ubuntu which can be used for connection of Windows thin clients? It is a big advantage if there are no limitation for a number of connected thin clients.

Thank you for possible recomendations and support.

Comment: yes...sorry now i'm being retarded.....when i can find the package name i'll post a solution

Comment: What are you looking for?. Software to let linux clients connect Windows TS?. Software to let windows clients act as thin clients for a linux server?. Linux2linux?

Comment: Dear Javier. I am looking an alternative to MS Terminal server, which may act as Terminal server for MS Windows (mostly WinXP and Win7) clients (thin clients). It is possible to use Win7 Pro edition, there are 5 (or 10) simultaneous connections with freeware Terminal server (not MS production). I am interested if there are other alternatives to XP(7) Pro + limited freeware terminal server for MS OSes.

Comment: So what you want is a piece of software you can install in Microsoft Windows that allows more than 5 or 10 people to remotely access the Windows host?

Comment: If you stay under windows as server then you can't escape to buy a windows server and CAL. The limitation is not on thin clients but on the server. The real restriction is at the "simultaneous connected users" : you can't escape it in any way because it's windows itself. In the particularity of Terminal Server then the restriction is also at the Terminal server level where you'll need also specific cal for that.

Comment: @ Antorine Rodriguez: I fully agree with you ! Please, put your comment as an answer. I will confirm it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

[LTSP project](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Terminal_Server_Project)